# Confuse about "dual_coef_" of OneClassSVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I have read the paper "Estimating the Support of a High-Dimensional Distribution" about [one-class-svm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) which provided in sklearn.

I notice that the dual variables have a constrain that ∑_i α_i =1.

But when I tried to call api `clf._dual_coef_`, I found the sum of the `clf._dual_coef_` wouldn't be 1.

Did I miss any detail about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Result

For one-class SVM, [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) solves a scaled problem that every α_i is multiplied by (νℓ), where ν is the hyper-parameter and ℓ is the number of instances. So the constraint becomes α_i≤1 and ∑_i α_i = νℓ.

---

## Reason

In Section 2.3 of [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf)

> Similar to the case of ν-SVC, in LIBSVM, we solve a scaled version of (7).

where in Section 2.2 (ν-Support Vector Classification) quoted

> In LIBSVM, we solve a scaled version of problem (5) because numerically α_i may be too small due to the constraint α_i≤1/ℓ.

So for one-class SVM, LIBSVM solves a scaled problem because numerically α_i may be too small due to the constraint α_i≤1/(νℓ).

---

## Verification

Specifically, because the question is about sklearn, I modify the code from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_outlier_detection_housing.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-outlier-detection-housing-py) to confirm thought, though from my understanding [sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn-svm-oneclasssvm) use LIBSVM in the backend.

```
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

X = load_boston()['data'][:, [8, 10]]
clf = OneClassSVM(nu=0.261, gamma=0.05)
clf.fit(X)

print(clf.nu*X.shape[0])
print(clf._dual_coef_.sum())
```

gives

```
132.066
132.06599999999918
```